Asymptotic behaviour of an infinite sum of Gaussian functions
Let us say I have a sum of Gaussian functions given by the form,
$$
G(x, t) = e^{-t/\tau} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{t}{\tau}\right)^n \frac{1}{n!} \frac{e^{-x^2/(4nx_0^2)}}{\sqrt{4\pi n x_0^2}}
$$
where is it evident that with increasing $n$ in the series, the variance grows. Also, the sum starts from $n=1$ because, it is not defined at $n=0$.
Is it possible to evaluate the asymptotic behaviour of $G(x,t)$ in two cases

For values of $x$ much larger than $x_0$ ($x \gg x_0$)
For values of $x$ much smaller than $x_0$ ($x \ll x_0$)

A possible approach
Is it possible to solve it more easily in the Fourier space, for example, if we define
$$
I(k,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx e^{-ikx} G(x,t)
$$
Then the original equation can be rewritten as,
$$
I(k,t) = e^{-t/\tau} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{t}{\tau}\right)^n \frac{e^{-n(kx_0)^2}}{n!}
$$
In this case, the conditions become

$kx_0 \ll 1$ (for $x \gg x_0$)
$kx_0 \gg 1$ (for $x \ll x_0$)


The series for $I(k, t)$ can be written in closed form.

Of course, it would become a double exponential function, but does that help me in calculating the asymptotic behaviour?

Just added the case of $a\gg1$

Partial solution
Let's consider
$$S(a,x,x_0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!}\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4nx_0^2}}}{\sqrt{4\pi nx_0^2}}=\frac1{\pi x_0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-4n\big(t-\frac {ix}{4nx_0}\big)^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4n x_0^2}}dt$$
$$=\frac1{\pi x_0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-4nt^2}e^{\frac{2ix}{x_0}t}dt=\frac1{\pi x_0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(e^{ae^{-4t^2}}-1\right)e^{\frac{2ix}{x_0}t}dt\tag{1}$$
In the case of $\frac x{x_0}\ll1$ we can decompose the second term in the integrand and get
$$S=\frac1{\pi x_0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(e^{ae^{-4t^2}}-1\right)\left(1+\frac{2ix}{x_0}t-\frac{2x^2}{x_0^2}t^2+...\right)dt$$
$$=\frac1{\pi x_0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(e^{ae^{-4t^2}}-1\right)dt-\frac{2x^2}{\pi x_0^3}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(e^{ae^{-4t^2}}-1\right)t^2dt+O\left(\frac {x^4}{x_0^4}\right)$$
$$\overset{IBP}{=}\frac{8a}{\pi x_0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ae^{-4t^2}-4t^2}t^2dt-\frac{16ax^2}{3\pi x_0^3}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ae^{-4t^2}-4t^2}t^4dt+O\left(\frac {x^4}{x_0^4}\right)\tag{2}$$
I may suppose this is the most general form - unless we have some additional information about $a$
Integrating (1) by parts,
$$S(a,x,x_0)=\frac1{2\pi i x}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{2ix}{x_0}t}e^{ae^{-4t^2}-4t^2}tdt=\frac1{\pi x}\int_0^\infty e^{ae^{-4t^2}-4t^2}\sin\left(\frac{2x}{x_0}t\right)tdt$$
$$=-\frac1{\pi x}\frac{\partial}{\partial\frac x{x_0}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ae^{-4t^2}-4t^2}\cos\left(\frac{2x}{x_0}t\right)dt\tag{3}$$
$$=-\frac1{\pi x}\Re\frac{\partial}{\partial\frac x{x_0}}\frac x{x_0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ae^{-4\frac{x^2}{x_0^2}s^2}-4\frac{x^2}{x_0^2}s^2+2i\frac{x^2}{x_0^2}s}ds$$
Considering the case $\frac x{x_0}\gg1$, I'm afraid we cannot proceed any further without the information about $a$ (for example, $a\gg1$, $a\ll1$)

Now, let's consider the case of $a\gg1$

$\displaystyle \lambda=\frac x{x_0}\ll1$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ae^{-4t^2}-4t^2}t^2dt=\frac18\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ae^{-s^2}-s^2}s^2ds\overset{e^{-s^2}=t}{=}\frac18\int_0^1e^{at}\sqrt{-\ln t}dt$$
$$=\frac{e^a}8\int_0^1 e^{-at}\sqrt{-\ln (1-t)}dt=\frac{e^a}{8a}\int_0^a e^{-t}\sqrt{-\ln \Big(1-\frac ta\Big)}dt$$
$$\sim\frac{e^a}{8a}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sqrt{\frac ta}dt=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{32}\frac{e^a}{a^{\frac32}}$$
In the same way,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ae^{-4t^2}-4t^2}t^4dt\sim\frac{e^a}{32a}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\Big(\frac ta\Big)^\frac32dt=\frac{3\sqrt \pi}{256}\frac{e^a}{a^{\frac52}}$$
Putting this into (2)
$$S(a,x,x_0)= \frac1{4\sqrt\pi x_0}\frac{e^a}{\sqrt a}\left(1+O\Big(\frac1a\Big)\right)+\frac{x^2}{16\sqrt\pi x_0^3}\frac{e^a}{a^\frac32}\left(1+O\Big(\frac1a\Big)\right)+O\left(\frac {x^4}{x_0^4}\right)$$


The case $\displaystyle\lambda=\frac x{x_0}\gg1$ is more complicated and the answer depends also on the ratio $\displaystyle \frac a\lambda$. For example, at $a\gg\lambda\gg1$, using (3)
$$S(a,x,\lambda)=-\frac1{2\pi x}\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ae^{-s^2}-s^2}\cos\left(\lambda s\right)ds$$
$$\overset{e^{-s^2}=t}{=}-\frac1{2\pi x}\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\int_0^1 e^{at}\frac{\cos(\lambda\sqrt{-\ln t})}{\sqrt{-\ln t}}dt=\frac1{2\pi x}e^a\int_0^1e^{-at}\sin\big(\lambda\sqrt{-\ln(1- t)}\,\big)dt$$
$$=\frac1{2\pi x}\frac{e^a}\lambda\int_0^\lambda e^{-\frac a\lambda s}\sin\left(\lambda\sqrt{-\ln\Big(1- \frac s\lambda\Big)}\right)ds$$
$$\sim\frac1{2\pi x}\frac{e^a}\lambda\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac a\lambda s}\sin \sqrt{\lambda s}\,ds=\frac1{2\pi x}\frac{e^a}\lambda\Im\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac a\lambda s^2+i\sqrt\lambda s}\,s\,ds$$
$$=\frac1{4\sqrt\pi}\frac{e^a}{a^\frac32}\frac\lambda x\, e^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{4a}}=\frac1{4\sqrt\pi}\frac{e^a}{a^\frac32}\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4ax_0^2}}} {x_0} $$


I am particularly interested in the limit $a \gg 1$!
